# Google Maps zoom-in/zoom-out buttons tilted

Tags: css, reactjs, google-map-react

I am using `google-map-react` in one of my react sites:
https://pioneeredu.ca/school-boards/on-sb/ca-on-tdsb

The codes for generating the maps are almost the same as in the `google-map-react` examples. However, the zoom-in/zoom-out buttons are tilted. Spent some time on it but couldn't figure out what is causing this weird behavior. Could someone provide some clue for it?

Comment: What do you mean 'tilted'?

Comment: The zoom-in/zoom-out buttons are tiled to the left, instead of straight up.